# How to replace Smart Quotes with Straight Quote in Visual Basic (Classic ASP)?

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I have a process that essentially works like this:

1. MyText is inserted into textbox in MainForm.asp
2. MainForm.asp OnSubmit redirects to Submit.asp
3. In Submit.asp:

```
<% myText = Upload.Form("MyText") %>
myText = #<%=myText%>
<% myText = FixQuotes(myText) %>
```

4. myText is inserted into a sql database
5. View.asp calls myText from the database
6. View.asp prints myText

I'm running into a problem where smart quotes (curly quotes, where there's a difference between a beginning quote and end quotes) are printing as gibberish characters like `Ã¢â‚¬Å“` by the time we get to step 6.

I believe that the smart quotes still exist as themselves and not the gibberish by the time we get to step 3, and so I am attempting to use the following function to fix the quotes to straight quotes. I'm not sure exactly what my parameters for the `Replace()` should be, so an extra set of eyes would be helpful. What I currently have doesn't actually work.

```
Function FixQuotes (tempString)
        tempString = Replace(tempString, ChrW(&H201c), "&quote") 'double left quote
        tempString = Replace(tempString, ChrW(&H201d), """") 'double right quote
        FixQuotes = tempString
end function
```

However, it is quite possible that the quotes turn to the gibberish as soon as MainForm submits. In which case, I'm not really sure how I should handle the replacement.

For reference, I have `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">` in the heads of all my pages.

Edit: Additional information

Comment: The other option would be to have a JavaScript function that does the replace before the submit.  I've used that in the past.

Comment: Another option would be to configure the text encoding properly so you don’t have such issues

Comment: As @StephenR has pointed out you will have an encoding mismatch and the way to deal with that is not trying to `Replace()` the characters it's to correctly encode the content before it reaches the browser.

Comment: This is worth a read - `Response.CodePage = 65001` is probably the most useful suggestion.
https://www.hanselman.com/blog/InternationalizationAndClassicASP.aspx